# How to remove proxy from WebRequest and leave DefaultWebProxy untouched

Tags: c#, .net

I use FtpWebRequest to do some FTP stuff and I need to connect directly (no proxy). However WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy contains IE proxy settings (I reckon).

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("ftp://someftpserver/");
// request.Proxy is null here so setting it to null does not have any effect
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
// connects using WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy
```

My code is a piece in a huge application and I don't want to change `WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy` because it is global static property and it can have adverse impact on the other parts of the application.

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

try setting the proxy to an empty WebProxy, ie:

```
request.Proxy = new WebProxy();
```

This should create an empty proxy.

Comment: No probs, this one stumped me a little while ago.

Comment: It's worth noting that the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czdt10d3(v=vs.110).aspx) says to use `GlobalProxySelection.GetEmptyWebProxy()` to obtain an empty proxy. But if you try this Visual Studio will inform you that the `GlobalProxySelection` class is obsolete and you should use `WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy` instead ... which is exactly what the OP does **not** want.

Answer (score 9):

Actually setting it to null will be enough as well to disable auto proxy detection, you might save some cycles :)

```
request.Proxy = null;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fze2ytx2.aspx

Comment: Actually, setting to null didn't help if I remember correctly (as said in the snippet comment). Disabling auto proxy detection would affect the rest of the application which I can't do either. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

```
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(yourRequestUrl);
        if (webRequest.Proxy != null)
        {
            webRequest.Proxy = null;
        }

        webRequest.KeepAlive = true;
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourObject);
        ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] postBytes = encoder.GetBytes(json);
        webRequest.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
        webRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        String encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", userName, password)));
        webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
        Stream requestStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
        requestStream.Close();

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
        string result;
        using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
                result = rdr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to config:

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy enabled="false" useDefaultCredentials="false">
    <proxy />
    <bypasslist />
    <module />
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```